# Function trigger twice on modified html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried on local hosted website, if I modified the data in function on a html page, when I trigger the function, it will be execute for 2 times, 1 time is with default data and another time is is with modified data.

Why this happen?

Will it happen is real website?

If it will happen in real website, is it possible to check modified data or limit it to execute a JavaScript function?

```
<input type='button' onclick='test("a");' value='try' />
<script>function test(text){alert(text);}</script>
```

Comment: How do you "modify the data in function"?

Comment: just open the page, inspect element and edit the html

Comment: Then it will only run in your browser, javascript it client-side so if you add/edit/remove anything client-side via your browser it will only apply those changes for that client. That's just like downloading a .txt document from a website, editing it on your computer and saving the changes then asking if those changes have applied for anyone else....

Comment: ya, I can just load the data from server, but if I just want to reuse data in browser, it will be corrupted when user modified html data.